# Binded ComboBox lose Item names after clear and add objects to collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an `observableCollection` property in C# code and a `ComboBox` binded to this observable collection:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CameraInstances" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="250" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CameraSettingsManager.Observable, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CameraSettingsManager.EditingCameraIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   SelectionChanged="CameraInstances_OnSelectionChanged" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  
                                   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                   Height="30"/>
```

Also I have another `ComboBox` which works as filter for this and on `SelectionChanged` event I clear observable collection and ad new items according to selected filter:

```
public void Load(ObservableCollection<Object> objects, CameraBehavior behavior)
{
    try
    {
        objects.Clear();

        if (behavior == CameraBehavior.Undefined)
        {
            if (firstPersonCameraContainer.Count > 0)
            {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FirstPersonCamera> camera in firstPersonCameraContainer)
                 {
                     objects.Add(camera);
                 }
             }

             if (thirdPersonCameraContainer.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ThirdPersonCamera> camera in thirdPersonCameraContainer)
                 {
                     objects.Add(camera);
                 }
             }

             if (flightCameraContainer.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FlightCamera> camera in flightCameraContainer)
                 {
                     objects.Add(camera);
                 }
             }
         }
         else if (behavior == CameraBehavior.FirstPerson)
         {
             if (firstPersonCameraContainer.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FirstPersonCamera> camera in firstPersonCameraContainer)
                 {
                     objects.Add(camera);
                 }
             }
         }
         else if (behavior == CameraBehavior.ThirdPerson)
         {
             if (thirdPersonCameraContainer.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ThirdPersonCamera> camera in thirdPersonCameraContainer)
                 {
                     objects.Add(camera);
                 }
             }
         }
         else
             if (behavior == CameraBehavior.Flight)
             {
                 if (flightCameraContainer.Count > 0)
                 {
                     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FlightCamera> camera in flightCameraContainer)
                     {
                         objects.Add(camera);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         catch (Exception e)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(e.Message + e.StackTrace + e.TargetSite);
         }
     }
}
```

But actually after collection is updated in `ComboBox` It seems that `ComboBox` losing `ItemsSource`. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, problem was solved by myself. It was actually because I add to collection wrong type (Dictionary instead of concrete type).